# How do I extend the PATH used by the awesome window manager run command?

Tags: paths, awesome

I have a bin directory in my home directory.

I would like for the Run: shortcut to search that bin directory as well.

How do I add it to the Run search path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe by adding something as follow in the `/etc/profile` file?

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

If you have problems with the tilde (`~`), try `/home/$USER/bin`. If you're the only user on that computer anyway, you can always use `/home/ranson/bin`, of course.

Notes:

1. you can also do that in your own `~/.profile` file in which case the `/home/ranson/bin` path will work as is:

   export PATH=/home/ransom/bin:$PATH
2. you'll have to log out and log back in for that change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but it might help someone.
For the awesome V4.0 adding `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to `/etc/profile` did not do the trick.
I had to put this line into `~/.xsessionrc` file to make it work. It is sourced before window manager starts and that is what you would like to do.